# Using getAuthors() for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-sites-2016

getAuthors() in Google Apps Script returns an array, so I'm assuming it is intended to capture all people who have edited the page.  However, it only returns a single value, which seems to be the person who created the page.  If another person edits the page, it still returns an array containing only the first value.

1. Is getAuthor() intended to be limited to just the creator?
2. Is there any way to return an array with all of people who have worked on
   a page (those who have saved edits)?
3. If not, is possible to change the author?

   ```
   function testAuthor(){
     var site = SitesApp.getSite(DOMAIN, NAME);
     var decendents = site.getAllDescendants();

     for (var i=0;i<decendents.length; i++){
       Logger.log(decendents[i].getAuthors().join(', '));
     };
   }
   ```

Comment: Sites can have many owners,editors and viewers.  Pages have only one author and it is not possible up to now to access the page revision history with the default Sites service.  I don't think there is any way to change the author of a page, this is stored on page creation (creation date is available too).  Site app is not my favorite toy so maybe someone more qualified will bring more accuracy on this (that's why I write a comment and not an answer)

Comment: Thanks Serge.  Any idea why they would have getAuthors() return an array?

Comment: Not really... maybe in a future release ? I hope someone from GAS team will pay attention to your question ;-) You could ask for an enhancement on the issue tracker.